# How can I access the ID of the user that just completed registration form in Gravity Forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using the Gravity Forms registration plugin to register users on a website I am building and I am trying to add the ID of the newly created user to a URL which gets emailed to specific emails.

I found info herehttp://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Entry_Object that says you can get the current user ID of the logged in user however the value returns 0 because it seems as though the user isn't quite logged in at the time this function is called.

This is how I am currently trying to access the ID

```
add_action("gform_after_submission", "set_post_content_stuff", 10, 2);

function set_post_content_stuff($entry, $form){

//get id of user submitting the form
$currUserID = $entry['created_by'];

}
```

Does anyone know how to access the ID from the wp_users table when a new user is registered?

Comment: Use the `get_users` function with the `search` argument to look for users with the same email address(Using the value of the email field of your form). Then fetch their id.

Comment: Please contact the vendor for your support options. Otherwise provide the source-code.

Comment: maybe a little easier `$user_id = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );`. I'm just getting my toes wet in GF but I think you should put this in a feed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the gform_user_registered hook to access the recently created user id:

```
add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'send_user_email', 10, 4 );
function send_user_email($user_id, $feed, $entry, $user_pass) {
    // Add function to send email
}
```

See documentation: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_user_registered/